# Akka EventBus - are terminated subscribers automatically unsubscribed?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, playframework-2.2

I'm fairly new to Akka. So, please let me know if this question has been answered elsewhere.

I'm building a web server application using Scala Play and Akka. Within the server, I have a couple of Kafka consumers that read messages from certain Kafka topics. I also have multiple clients that open websocket connections (as actors) to the server. As each message is read from Kafka, the server should send the message to all or a subset of the clients via the respective websockets.

From what I've read online, I feel it would be a good idea to use the EventBus feature of Akka as follows:

- each Kafka topic would correspond to a unique channel in the EventBus.
- each client would subscribe to channels of its choice.

**Questions**

(a) Does it make sense to use an EventBus in this scenario? Or have I misunderstood the purpose of EventBus?

(b) When a client closes its websocket connection, would that websocket actor be automatically unsubscribed from the EventBus?

(c) If the answer to (b) is 'No', then how do I ensure that the stopped actor has been removed from the list of subscribers?

Comment: Terminated actors are unsubscribed automatically: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/event-bus.html#Actor_Classification

Comment: I just bumped into this question.
AFAIK it does make sense to use the EventBus, depending on your specific delivery requirements (if a message has to be delivered or not) I don't know if it's possible to use EventBus with persisted events to achieve at least once delivery.. (if someone knows, let me know :) )

What were your conclusions in the end?